# "Frozen" column when scrolling horizontal

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am new to c# and UWP and looking for a way to enable horizontal scrolling with frozen column.

Currently this is my list :

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

 <ListView x:Name="Listeoffice" ItemsSource ="{x:Bind salesoffices}" Margin="0,60,0,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate x:Name="Template1" x:DataType ="data:office">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,20,0,0" Width="700" >   
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind caption}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="50"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind invoices}" Margin="50,0,0,0" Width="90"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind order_entry}" Margin="30,0,10,0" Width="88"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind delivery_backlog}" Margin="10,0,20,0" Width="100"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind delivery_new}" Margin="10,0" Width="88"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind delivery_total}" Margin="20,0,10,0" Width="88"/>
                       </StackPanel>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The problem is with this approach when I scroll horizontal the first column will not stay.
I read something about using  a second ScrollViewer just for the first column but i cant get it working.

EDIT : 
Sry wasn´t precise enough. I dont want a header but the first column (the left one) to stay even if the list gets scrolled horizontal.

Comment: Maybe a bit of a hack, but can't you 'overlay' a single column listview on top of the other one? So that the other data will slide underneath it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want header of your ListView.
`ListView` has a `Header` property.

```
<ListView>
<ListView.Header>
  your header
</ListView.Header>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Change the listview to a datagrid and search this site for "how-to-freeze-first-column-of-wpf-datagrid"

Comment: Windows Phone doesn't have DataGrid control